# Error when using strings in c++.error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class

Tags: c++, string

I'm creating a C++ program using different functions for the first time, but whenever I've tried to use strings, this happens!

I will just post relevant parts.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<cctype>


using namespace std;

..... (Skipping irrelevant parts)

<Variables go here.>

..... (Skipping irrelevant parts)

    if (tolower(from) == 'a')
    {
        unit = "Seconds";
        secondsto();
    }

    else if (tolower(from) == 'b')
    {
        unit = "Minutes";
        minutesto();
    }
    else if (tolower(from) == 'c')
    {
        unit = "Hours";
        hoursto();
    }
    else if (tolower(from) == 'd')
    {
        unit = "Days";
        daysto();
    }
/*  else if (tolower(from) == 'e')
    {
        unit = "Weeks";
        weeksto();
    }*/
    else if (tolower(from) == 'f')
    {
        unit = "Months";
        monthsto();
    }
    else if (tolower(from) == 'g')
    {
        unit = "Years";
        yearsto();
    }
    ..... (Skipping irrelevant parts)

if (tolower(from) == 'a')
    {
        unit = "Seconds";
        secondsto();
    }

    else if (tolower(from) == 'b')
    {
        unit = "Minutes";
        minutesto();
    }
    else if (tolower(from) == 'c')
    {
        unit = "Hours";
        hoursto();
    }
    else if (tolower(from) == 'd')
    {
        unit = "Days";
        daysto();
    }
/*  else if (tolower(from) == 'e')
    {
        unit = "Weeks";
        weeksto();
    }*/
    else if (tolower(from) == 'f')
    {
        unit = "Months";
        monthsto();
    }
    else if (tolower(from) == 'g')
    {
        unit = "Years";
        yearsto();
    }


...... (Skipping)

        cout << original_value << " " << unit << " --> " << value << " " << new_unit;
```

The error is exactly

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' (or there is no a
cceptable conversion)
```

I tried almost every other solution I could find and no luck.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` not `#include<iostream.h>`

Comment: Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What are types of `original_value`, `unit`, `value` and `new_unit`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not include deprecated `iostream.h` but `<iostream>` in your program. Also `switch` would be more readable and eliminate code duplicate rather than cascade `if/else`:

```
switch ( tolower(from) ) {
   case 'a' :
      unit = "Seconds";
      secondsto();
      break;
   case 'b' :
      unit = "Minutes";
      minutesto();
      break;
     ...
 }
```

also you would eliminate multiple call to `tolower()` function.

Comment: Technical note: `iostream.h` is not deprecated. It simply doesn't exist. Formally, deprecation is a warning that something in the standard may go away in a future revision of the standard. `iostream.h` was never in the standard, so was never deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

with

```
#include <iostream>
```

You should also try to avoid

```
using namespace std;
```

and use

```
using std::cout;
```

or

```
std::cout << original_value << " " << unit << " --> " << value << " " << new_unit;
```